# Web app for music identification which can be used on PC

Tags: web-apps, hosted, music-recognition

I'm looking for a site to which I can upload an audio file and identify what music is playing in it.

Kinda like [Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_(service)), but without the need to have a smartphone, and without listening through microphone.

I'm planning on using it on Windows and mobile devices which do not support the actual Shazam app because they're too old. It doesn't have to have a Windows native version, but it has to work at least on Windows in a browser.

---

Before posting an answer, please check that what you found works, because there are some sites out there which are still online but say their servers are "on maintenance" or "can't be found".

Answer (score 1):

What I found is [AudioTag](http://audiotag.info/index.php). (And I did just try it and it worked.)

It is an in-browser app, you upload your music (or you can provide a URL leading to the file) and it checks against a database to propose to you the most probable titles of the piece.

Comment: What do you mean by "it runs on Windows"? If it's an in-browser app/web service in which you just need to upload a file, it doesn't change anything if you're in Windows or another OS, or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Also, about AudioTag, as of october 2017: `Statistics: 
recognized queries: 2170505; DB size: 2136533 tracks, 160033 albums; last DB update: 65 days ago; added 32322 tracks, 0 albums`

Comment: No, you're right, I was just being too focused on the question, "it has to work at least on Windows in a browser." I'll edit it out to avoid further confusion.